# Arduino: fill array with values from analogRead()

Tags: arrays, arduino, multitasking

How do I fill an array with values from [`analogRead()`](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/analog-io/analogread/) on an Arduino?

At a fixed interval of once per second, I want to read a value from analog input pin `A0` via `analogRead(A0`), and store these values into an array.

Ideally, other code would also be able to run during the time between measurements.

Comment: Have you tried looping?

Answer (score 6):

Let's say you want to read up to 100 values, do this:

### 1. Poor technique (uses blocking code with `delay()`)

```cpp
//let's say you want to read up to 100 values
const unsigned int numReadings = 100;
unsigned int analogVals[numReadings];
unsigned int i = 0;

void setup()
{
}

void loop()
{
  analogVals[i] = analogRead(A0);
  i++;
  if (i>=numReadings)
  {
    i=0; //reset to beginning of array, so you don't try to save readings outside of the bounds of the array
  }
  delay(1000); //wait 1 sec
}
```

Note: you cannot make the number in brackets too large. Ex: `analogVals[2000]` will not work because it takes up too much RAM.

Note: the above type approach is also covered in Arduino's basic tutorials on the website. Please reference here: https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/ --> click on "array" under "Data Types" --> at the bottom of [this page it takes you to](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/variables/data-types/array/), click ["How to Use Arrays example](https://docs.arduino.cc/built-in-examples/control-structures/Arrays).

There are a lot of other really useful "Built-in Examples" here: https://docs.arduino.cc/built-in-examples/.

### 2. Alternate method (also a poor technique, since it uses blocking code with `delay()`)

```cpp
//let's say you want to read up to 100 values
const unsigned int numReadings = 100;
unsigned int analogVals[numReadings];

void setup()
{
}

void loop()
{
  //take numReadings # of readings and store into array
  for (unsigned int i=0; i<numReadings; i++)
  {
    analogVals[i] = analogRead(A0);
    delay(1000); //wait 1 sec
  }
}
```

### 3. Better technique (non-blocking method--no `delay`!)

```cpp
//let's say you want to read up to 100 values
const unsigned int numReadings = 100;
unsigned int analogVals[numReadings];
unsigned int i = 0;

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(115200);
}

void loop()
{
  static uint32_t tStart = millis(); // ms; start time
  const uint32_t DESIRED_PERIOD = 1000; // ms
  uint32_t tNow = millis(); // ms; time now
  if (tNow - tStart >= DESIRED_PERIOD)
  {
    tStart += DESIRED_PERIOD; // update start time to ensure consistent and near-exact period

    Serial.println("taking sample");
    analogVals[i] = analogRead(A0);
    i++;
    if (i>=numReadings)
    {
      i = 0; //reset to beginning of array, so you don't try to save readings outside of the bounds of the array
    }
  }
}
```

### 4. Professional-type approach (non-blocking method, avoids global variables by passing around pointers instead, uses [C stdint types](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdint/), and uses static variables to store local, persistent data)

```cpp
// Function prototypes
// - specify default values here
bool takeAnalogReadings(uint16_t* p_numReadings = nullptr, uint16_t** p_analogVals = nullptr);

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(115200);
  Serial.println("\nBegin\n");
}

void loop()
{
  // This is one way to just take readings
  // takeAnalogReadings();

  // This is a way to both take readings *and* read out the values when the buffer is full
  uint16_t numReadings;
  uint16_t* analogVals;
  bool readingsDone = takeAnalogReadings(&numReadings, &analogVals);
  if (readingsDone)
  {
    // Let's print them all out!
    Serial.print("numReadings = "); Serial.println(numReadings);
    Serial.print("analogVals = [");
    for (uint16_t i=0; i<numReadings; i++)
    {
      if (i!=0)
      {
        Serial.print(", ");
      }
       Serial.print(analogVals[i]);
    }
    Serial.println("]");
  }
}

// Function definitions:

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Take analog readings to fill up a buffer.
// Once the buffer is full, return true so that the caller can read out the data.
// Optionally pass in a pointer to get access to the internal buffer in order to read out the data from outside
// this function.
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
bool takeAnalogReadings(uint16_t* p_numReadings, uint16_t** p_analogVals)
{
  static const uint16_t NUM_READINGS = 10;
  static uint16_t i = 0; // index
  static uint16_t analogVals[NUM_READINGS];

  const uint32_t SAMPLE_PD = 1000; // ms; sample period (how often to take a new sample)
  static uint32_t tStart = millis(); // ms; start time
  bool bufferIsFull = false; // set to true each time NUM_READINGS have been taken

  // Only take a reading once per SAMPLE_PD
  uint32_t tNow = millis(); // ms; time now
  if (tNow - tStart >= SAMPLE_PD)
  {
    Serial.print("taking sample num "); Serial.println(i + 1);
    tStart += SAMPLE_PD; // reset start time to take next sample at exactly the correct pd
    analogVals[i] = analogRead(A0);
    i++;
    if (i >= NUM_READINGS)
    {
      bufferIsFull = true;
      i = 0; // reset to beginning of array, so you don't try to save readings outside of the bounds of the array
    }
  }

  // Assign the user-passed-in pointers so that the user can retrieve the data if they so desire to do it this way
  if (p_numReadings != nullptr)
  {
    *p_numReadings = NUM_READINGS;
  }
  if (p_analogVals != nullptr)
  {
    *p_analogVals = analogVals;
  }

  return bufferIsFull;
}
```

Sample Serial Monitor output from the last code just above:

```
Begin  

taking sample num 1  
taking sample num 2  
taking sample num 3  
taking sample num 4  
taking sample num 5  
taking sample num 6  
taking sample num 7  
taking sample num 8  
taking sample num 9  
taking sample num 10  
numReadings = 10  
analogVals = [1023, 1023, 1023, 1023, 1023, 687, 0, 0, 0, 0]  
taking sample num 1  
taking sample num 2  
taking sample num 3  
taking sample num 4  
taking sample num 5  
taking sample num 6  
taking sample num 7  
taking sample num 8  
taking sample num 9  
taking sample num 10  
numReadings = 10  
analogVals = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

### More reading/study:

1. **My thorough answer on [How to do high-resolution, timestamp-based, non-blocking, single-threaded cooperative multi-tasking](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50032992/4561887)**
2. Arduino's very basic but *extremely useful* "Blink Without Delay" tutorial: https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/BlinkWithoutDelay
3. Other "Build-in Examples" from Arduino: https://docs.arduino.cc/built-in-examples/

Comment: How can analogRead return either an int or an unsigned int?

Comment: According to the [source code on line 38 here](https://github.com/arduino/ArduinoCore-avr/blob/master/cores/arduino/wiring_analog.c) `analogRead()` returns an `int`. However, since the range is only 0-1023, it would make the most sense to store it into a `uint16_t`, which is the equivalent of `unsigned int` on ATmega328-based Arduinos. The compiler will automatically cast types as required to make them get stored into alternate types (ex: `unsigned int` <--> `int`), with loss of data only if you are outside the valid bounds of the new type. In this case it is safe.

Comment: It is safe because `analogRead` returns 0-1023, and `unsigned int` can store values from 0 to 65,535 (see https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/variables/data-types/unsignedint/), while `int` can store values from -32,768 to 32,767 (see https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/variables/data-types/int/). As you can see, both can easily store values in the 0-1023 range.